# How to require email validation in Cognito through CloudFormation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-cognito

I think I tried all properties here:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-cognito-userpool.html

couldn't get this box checked:

[image]

My config currently:

```
    CognitoUserPoolGeneral:
      Type: AWS::Cognito::UserPool
      Properties:
        UserPoolName: general
        Policies:
          PasswordPolicy:
            MinimumLength: 6
            RequireLowercase: false
            RequireNumbers: false
            RequireSymbols: false
            RequireUppercase: false
        Schema:
          - AttributeDataType: String
            Name: preferredLocale
            DeveloperOnlyAttribute: false
            Mutable: true
            Required: false
        EmailVerificationMessage: "Here's your verification code: {####}. Please provide it inside the application."
        EmailVerificationSubject: "subject"
```

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You can add

```
  AutoVerifiedAttributes:
    - email
```

To your `Properties` key, like so:

```
  UserPool:
    Type: "AWS::Cognito::UserPool"
    Properties:
      UserPoolName: !Sub ${AuthName}-user-pool
      AutoVerifiedAttributes:
        - email
      Policies:.....
```

For an excellent example of a CloudFormation template that creates Cognito resources, see:

https://gist.github.com/singledigit/2c4d7232fa96d9e98a3de89cf6ebe7a5

Comment: Wait. How does 'AutoVerifiedAttributes' translate to 'Require Verification'??

Comment: @Birowsky I agree 100%, `AutoVerifiedAttributes` is a **terrible** name.

Comment: It means something like: 
**automatically start email verification**
When I was looking over it, I thought it meant: 
**email doesn't need verification, set it to verified automatically**.

Comment: if i add email and phone_number both to this field, will it verify both the attributed? or any one?

Comment: @YashKalwani Never tried, but I am guessing yes since it accepts an array.

Comment: Doesn't AutoVerifiedAttributes list the attributes that are verified automatically without actual verification?